# hcboxplot not building correct boxplots

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

While working on a project, I had a dataframe with a column for which I needed to build a boxplot using highcharter.

The column looked like this:

```
head(data,20)
   Col1
1    30
2    30
3    30
4    30
5    28
6    27
7    29
8    27
9    30
10   30
11   28
12   29
13   29
14   30
15   30
16   30
17   30
18   29
19   30
20   NA
```

and so on.. data has 693 observations. The data is 'labelled' and hence while building the boxplot, I use as.numeric().

When I try building boxplot with hcboxplot ->

```
hcboxplot(x = as.numeric(data$Col1[!is.na(data$Col1)]))
```

The boxplot details I get are -

Maximum: 30

Upper Quartile: 30

Median: 29

Lower Quartile: 28

Minimum: 25 
But in data, there definitely are values less than 25 (even 0)

```
> min(data$Col1[!is.na(data$Col1)])
[1] 0
```

So, the maximum value is correct but minimum definitely is not.
Why is the boxplot not coming out right ? Any help is appreciated! Apologies for not being able to add a pic to the question (Reputation restrictions).

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked out the `outliers` argument? Maybe you see your min values as dots. I've tried and I saw a zero as a dot outside the boxplot...

Comment: hi @patL ,thank you for your reply. No they were not showing up as outliers. I have outliers = TRUE set.

Comment: that's odd. As I told before, I've tried and it works for me...

Comment: Is your problem related to this Gitub issue: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/337?

Comment: @jordan I think yes!